# Is building Perl an inside joke or is it supposed to require this many `make` invocations?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, perl

So I am building Perl version 5.18.2 from source on an ARMv7 processor right now, a Krait on the Snapdragon S4, and I am not too sure how much support there is for such an architecture. By the way, I am trying to build an LFS system. The thing is for two days I have been stuck at Perl. I tried different users, as root, with CFLAGS, without CFLAGS, Debian source versions 5.16 and 5.18 and I always got stuck at a particular build step.

So this last time around I decided to pay attention to that message that says,

```
==> Your Makefile has been rebuilt. <==
==> Please rerun the make command.  <==
```

or something like that.

So I made a little for loop...

```
RET=$?; for i in `seq 10`; do if [ ! $RET -eq 0 ]; then echo " \

RETURN ${i} == ${RET} \

" && make; RET=$?; fi; done
```

... I started with seq 3, and sure enough after each one it *seems* to be making progress along the build. That is, it fails at a different step and when I check the log I see that the last step it failed at succeeded and I see the same message:

```
==> Your Makefile has been rebuilt. <==
==> Please rerun the make command.  <==
```

I skimmed over the build instructions at CPAN and didn't see any references, or anything indicating I should expect to go through this,
so it begs the question.

Is this some sort of inside joke, or am I doing something terribly wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I think the message was telling me to do the right thing, although it seems infeasible to sit at one's prompt and to type make over 50 plus times (may have been over 100 times), so I wrote this little while loop before I went to bed :

```
RET=$?; while [ ! $RET -eq 0 ]; do echo " \

RETURN == ${RET} \

"; make; RET=$?; done
```

And let it run. I did `Ctrl+z` it to stop the job while I slept and then I used `fg 1` to bring it back up this after-noon 1 because it was the only job I had, it may be different for someone else, research the `jobs`, `fg` and `bg` commands for more info.

I realize it may have been an endless loop but I could have always killed it with `Ctrl-c`. It seems to have always returned 2 so perhaps testing `while [ $RET -eq 2 ]; do` would have been more ideal.

To my surprise it just ended with a return of 0 with this message:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lfs/sources/perl/perl-5.18.2/x2p'

    Everything is up to date. Type 'make test' to run test suite.
```

So now I shall go on with the Linux From Scratch. It seems that perhaps when configuring a build from scratch, whatever makefiles are present on the system need to be rebuilt, so I am going to say that this was normal behavior, the repetitive `make` that is, and that not everything builds like "standard" GNU programs.

Hopefully that helps someone in the future.

Update:

This is the result of the test suite:

```
    Failed 10 tests out of 2247, 99.55% okay.
        ../cpan/CPANPLUS/t/03_CPANPLUS-Internals-Source.t
        ../cpan/Socket/t/socketpair.t
        ../cpan/Sys-Syslog/t/syslog.t
        ../cpan/Time-HiRes/t/alarm.t
        ../cpan/Time-HiRes/t/clock.t
        ../cpan/Time-HiRes/t/usleep.t
        ../dist/ExtUtils-Command/t/cp.t
        op/alarm.t
        op/sigdispatch.t
        op/sleep.t
```

99.55% success, not bad.

Since this is for the temporary tools created in chapter 5 of "Linux From Scratch" and they say the test suit is not required, and that I only need to copy some of the libs over to the `/tools` directory, I'm going to call this a success.

Comment: o_O Thank you for your feedback. I can't believe that this is the expected behavior... Perhaps you could ask to the Perl gurus on their mailing list?

Comment: I should do that, and will when I get around to it, may not be right this instant or today, but in the next few days at the latest, I will. LOL, "Please rerun the make command" for each "module" if you will, does seem rather ridiculous. The error was always, something along the lines of "... make file is out of date with respect to Makefile.PL" Maybe a timestamp issue with respect to file creation? I did notice that `date` always returned UTC instead of CDT, although the UTC time was correct +/- a minute.